# sending bytes from Raspberry Pi (using python) to a java android application over bluetooth

Tags: java, android, python, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project to control a robot using a mobile app. So far i have managed to send Bluetooth commands to make robot  move as wanted. But i am having trouble receiving input from the Ultrasonic Sensor HC-SR04 which gives a float vale every second. i have written code to convert the float to bytes then write the bytes to serial and read and display them on textview using java for the application.
But i only get a question mark on the textview which i a am assuming shows i am able to receive data on the channel, either the bytes are not complete or my conversions are wrong?

Please help.

##########here is my python script to send bytes

```
while True:
        a = ser.read()  #read from the serial  port
        ser.close()
        dist = initio.getDistance()    #distance obtained from ultra sensor       
        d = int(a.encode('hex'), 16) 
        bytSend = struct.pack('f', dist)  #convert the int distance to bytes
        ser.open()
        ser.write(bytSend)
```

**********here is the java code to read data on the stream and send to a handler on my main code***************

```
public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity

                    mHandler.obtainMessage(initioActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

*****then in  my main code (inside a handler) i have***

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
                //byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                //construct a string from valid bytes in buffer
                String distance = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                myLabel.setText(distance);
```

Any ideas what i may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

assume some distance d

```
d = 23.45454
```

therfore encoded message is

```
encoded_d = struct.pack("f",d)
print repr(encoded_d) # '\xe6\xa2\xbbA'
```

so when you read in the string in java you get that ...
since those are not valid characters you get `?` for any non-valid character

you need to figure out how to `decode` it back to a float in java

to resolve this the easiest way is probably to just send it as ascii

```
d = 23.45454
ser.write(str(d))
```

this will make your message passing fractionally slower but unless it is actually a problem, it should suffice

*all code in this post is python*

Comment: Thank you your response Joran. I will look into ways i can decode it back to float in java. About your sugested solution, it did not work, I even tried with the exact example you gave above.                I still get ? on my application or did i have to make changes on it too?

Comment: no you should not have had to made changes to your client code ... (but im not really great with java so maybe you need to tell it to decode it as an ascii string or something)

Comment: Ok, i have tried looking into different ways of encoding but no luck yet. Tried 'UTF-8' and 'US-ASCII' but they not supported.  Atleast this gives me something although i dont know how to inteprete it...                       byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
String distance = Arrays.toString(readBuf);
myLabel.setText(distance);                                                                          this givess just get [-8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0..........    which i dont know what it means